# How to add or replace string between specific string?

Tags: php, search, text, replace, addition

I need used PHP for replace or add new text in text file between specific example.

add **new string** in to area between **[auto update text]** old string **[/end auto update text]** in text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is something like this

```
$text = "[auto update text][/end auto update text]";

$text = preg_replace('/(?<=\[auto update text\]).*?(?=\[\/end auto update text\])/', 'Thing to add', $text);

echo $text;
```

output is `[auto update text]Thing to add[/end auto update text]`

For BBCode-style convention, you should probably make your tags something like `[autoupdate][/autoupdate]` instead.

Comment: @grudphunsanit Glad to hear it! If you found the answer helpful, please consider upvoting and marking this answer with the checkmark. Thanks. :)